# SQLstatements returns different values in MS Access & MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQLStatement to return the max value from a table. It works in SQL Server, but Microsoft Access sorts the values based on the first number only (and not the number as a whole) thus returning the wrong tuple.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Currency Code], [Relational Exch_ Rate Amount]
from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Currency Exchange Rate]
ORDER BY [Relational Exch_ Rate Amount] DESC
```

So the correct answer should return: 
GBP | 1354.xxx

and in access i get: 
HKD | 97.xxx

I have also tried

```
SELECT [Currency Code], MAX([Relational Exch_ Rate Amount])
FROM [CRONUS Sverige AB$Currency Exchange Rate]
```

It works with just MAX(columnName), but when i add [Currency Code] in front/after it just returns the wrong value.

EDIT: It seems Access is sorting the numerical value by letters rather than the actual numbers. I tried to find a way to change this - but without results. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: what datatype is `[Relational Exch_ Rate Amount]`?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting `GROUP BY`

```
    SELECT [Currency Code], MAX([Relational Exch_ Rate Amount])
    FROM [CRONUS Sverige AB$Currency Exchange Rate]
    GROUP BY [Currency Code]
```

Comment: It works to run, but I want to just extract 1 row from the DB. With this statement I get a lot of rows and just sorted by the Currency Code letter. (AED first & ZAR last). GBP (which is the max value I want it to return) is #15 in the list.

Comment: @user2868900 , if you have different `[Currency Code]`, it will return many rows, unless your `[Currency Code]` is all the same.. but if you want to `SELECT` only 1 rows i think that's illogical because you are getting the `MAX` with different `[Currency Code]`, the only `MAX` you can get is the max per `[Currency Code]`

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the top 1 after grouping and ordering should get you what you want

```
SELECT top 1 [Currency Code], MAX([Relational Exch_ Rate Amount])
FROM [CRONUS Sverige AB$Currency Exchange Rate]
GROUP BY [Currency Code]
order by MAX([Relational Exch_ Rate Amount]) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The trick was to use Val([Relational Exch_ Rate Amount]) in my SQL statement for Access to recognize the numerical value.

Now it seems like it's working fine.

Thanks for all the support